# Android - Is there a way to tell programmatically if a SharedPreferences file is created?

Tags: android

What I want to do is tell my main activity if there is a SharedPreferences file, change a bunch of strings using the values in the file. And if there is no SharedPreferences file created yet, use the default strings that are assigned in the layout (essentially do nothing).

Answer (score 2):

You can save preferences with this snippet:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString(yourkey, yourvalue);
    edit.commit();
```

And you can fetch them using this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    sp.getString(yourkey,defaultvalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the [SharedPreferences#getString(String key, String defaultValue)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) API that let's you specify a default value?

Comment: What would defaultValue return if there is no SharedPreferences file created?

Comment: @tuzion Don't worry about files being created, the `SharedPreferences` API abstracts that away for you. If you haven't previously set a `value` for a particular `key`, whatever you pass in for `defaultValue` is returned.

Comment: So do I technically even need to worry about any of this, then? If a file isn't created will the lines containing SharedPreferences just be ignored? I was thinking an error on one of my pages was because of it not being created but I could just be wrong.

Comment: Maybe this example will help -- `String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "Bob");`. If you previously called `sharedPreferences.put("name", "Jim")`, `getString` will return `"Jim"`.  If you previously didn't set a value for `"name"`, the default value `"Bob"` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(key, defValue).